# use subplot for ploting multiple graph in matlab

Tags: matlab, subplot

i can't understand what is reason for following error?here is given  code

```
for i=1:20 
      x(i) = i-10; 
      squared(i) = x(i) ^ 2; 
      cube(i) = x(i) ^ 3; 
      linear(i) = x(i); 
      log_of(i) = log(x(i)); 
      sqrt_of(i) = sqrt(x(i)); 
    end 
    subplot(2,3,1); 
    plot(x,squared); 
    title('square'); 

        subplot(2,3,4); 
    plot(sqrt_of,cube); 
    title('sqrt'); 

    subplot(2,3,5); 
    plot(linear,cube); 
    title('linear'); 

    subplot(2,3,6); 
    plot(log_of,cube); 
    title('log'); 


    subplot(2,3,3); 
    plot(x,cube); 
    title('cube');
```

and error says

```
subplot1
Attempt to execute SCRIPT subplot as a function:
C:\Users\D.Datuashvili\Desktop\subplot.m

Error in subplot1 (line 9)
    subplot(2,3,1);
```

it seems  everything  ok in code, but why is following error?could you help me?
EDITED:

```
for i=1:20 
      x(i) = i-10; 
      squared(i) = x(i).^ 2; 
      cube(i) = x(i).^ 3; 
      linear(i) = x(i); 
      log_of(i) = log(x(i)); 
      sqrt_of(i) = sqrt(x(i)); 
    end 
    subplot(2,3,1); 
    plot(x,squared); 
    title('square'); 

        subplot(2,3,4); 
    plot(sqrt_of,cube); 
    title('sqrt'); 

    subplot(2,3,5); 
    plot(linear,cube); 
    title('linear'); 

    subplot(2,3,6); 
    plot(log_of,cube); 
    title('log'); 


    subplot(2,3,3); 
    plot(x,cube); 
    title('cube');
```

error:

```
 subplot1
Error using plot
Vectors must be the same lengths.

Error in subplot1 (line 10)
    plot(x,squared);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably there is a file named subplot in your workspace

Comment: what is C:\Users\D.Datuashvili\Desktop\subplot.m ? is it matlab's own  function or your file?

Comment: i have   changed directory now,but whenever i run it shows me only one figure

Comment: it says  that vector should be  same length,i  have done some changes, and upload now

Comment: x and squared arrays have different lengths, you can try clearing those variables by adding clear all to the begining of the m file

Comment: now it works,thanks  a lot,so it is better to use clear all always  when writing M-file?

Comment: yes, clearing variables may simplify things. You may also need to clear only specific variables and you can use clearvars for this purpose

Answer (score 0):

As noted above, the first error most comes from your file C:\Users\D.Datuashvili\Desktop\subplot.m which shadows the Matlab default.

the second error comes from the fact that the length of array `squared` is longer, probably because you changed it earlier.

just add the following line before your script and it will be fine

```
 clear squared cube linear log-of sqrt_of
```